# How to use SUM and MAX functions together in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    G.NAME AS GENRE, 
    COUNT(T.NAME) AS TotalTransactions, 
    f.country, SUM(il.unitprice) AS Spent
FROM 
    final F
JOIN 
    CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMERID = F.CUSTOMERID
JOIN 
    INVOICE I ON I.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
JOIN 
    INVOICELINE IL ON IL.INVOICEID = I.INVOICEID
JOIN 
    TRACK T ON T.TRACKID = IL.TRACKID
JOIN 
    GENRE G ON G.GENREID = T.GENREID
GROUP BY 
    G.NAME, c.country
ORDER BY 
    G.NAME;
```

Desired output:

```
 GENRE           TotalTransactions   Country   Spent
 ----------------------------------------------------
 Alternative              5          USA         4.95
 Alternative & Punk      36          Canada     35.64
```

For example, I only want for the Alternative Genre USA since they spent the most on alternative music.

I tried using MAX(SUM()) but that gave me a group error. Thanks!

Comment: Please replace images with formatted sample data and desired output. Also tag your rdbms. Look into `row_number() over (partition by column order by spent desc)` but without desired output is difficult to determine what you need here.

Comment: @Isolated I have updated the post. This is my first time posting on here; I am very stuck on how to use SUM and MAX together. I have to create multiple queries and all my ideas consist of using some sort of MAX function with another function, but I can't figure out how to use them together.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question so we can actually help you. Do take care to include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [tag your RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) and [to not use pictures in all that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to subquery to rank the sums, per genre, and query again to pull the top one for each genre.

```
;WITH Normalized AS
(
    SELECT  
        G.NAME AS GENRE, 
        COUNT(T.NAME) AS TotalTransactions, 
        f.country, SUM(il.unitprice) AS Spent       
    FROM 
        final F
    JOIN 
        CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMERID = F.CUSTOMERID
    JOIN 
        INVOICE I ON I.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
    JOIN 
        INVOICELINE IL ON IL.INVOICEID = I.INVOICEID
    JOIN 
        TRACK T ON T.TRACKID = IL.TRACKID
    JOIN 
        GENRE G ON G.GENREID = T.GENREID
    GROUP BY 
        G.NAME, c.country
)
,Ranked AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GENRE ORDER BY Spent DESC) AS GenreRank
    FROM
        Normalized  
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Ranked  
WHERE
    GenreRank = 1
ORDER BY 
    [NAME];
```

Or even better

```
;WITH Normalized AS
(
   ...
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
   Normalized   
HAVING RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GENRE ORDER BY Spent DESC) = 1
```